# Electric field inside the "Dees" of a Cyclotron and why no "Cups"

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-fields, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

I read about cyclotron and how does it work. Several references say that the particle to be accelerated is only accelerated when it is between the gaps of the "Dees" or the semicircular disc like metallic containers. These "Dees" are connected to the RF source or the Oscillator.

I don't understand why would there be no electric field inside the "Dees". I know why would any point inside a cavity in a conductor would have zero electric field due to electrostatic shielding. BUT since the "Dees" have an open cavity and not a fully enclosed cavity, shouldn't there should be some E-field inside the "Dees"? Saying that there is no field inside the "Dees" should be like saying that a hemispherical shell can only have electric field on its outer surface, right? Then why is it said so?

Also, can hemispherical shells be used instead of the "Dees" in a cyclotron? Why? or why not?

Comment: Correct, the field does enter the Dees somewhat. See e.g. http://player.slideplayer.com/14/4178449/data/images/img26.jpg, full presentation at http://slideplayer.com/slide/4178449/, the image is from slide 24.

Comment: @CuriousOne What about hemispherical shells?

Comment: I don't know what the particle path inside a hemispherical shell would look like (my guess is that it would be unstable) ... but it wouldn't be useful to begin with because a very strong magnetic field is needed. It's hard enough to produce that for the flat Dees, producing it for a spherical volume would require a humungous magnet (today it would be easier with superconductors, back in the days of cyclotrons it would have been extremely cumbersome).

Comment: @CuriousOne Wouldn't the path be same as that in "Dees"?  circular like?

Comment: Why would it be the same? They symmetry is completely different.

Comment: But magnetic field makes the particle go in a circle, right? Ignoring the electric field of the hemispheres. ( which would still be symmetrical along the plane of revolution )

Comment: You can't ignore the electric fields. They are acting like electrostatic lenses. Cyclotrons only work because the particles are making relatively few passes, in other accelerators one has to have active beam optics with electrostatic or magnetic lenses (or both) to keep the beam together. That's why I don't believe that one can change the geometry and assume that it all keeps working. It might, but I wouldn't rely on it without a stability calculation.

Comment: Lawrence ' s first prototype of the cyclotron,  I believe was 6 inches in diameter and it actually used only 1 D.  The tank itself served as the other electrode. Faraday ' s law, Maxwell ' s equation says that the field cannot penetrate the closed conductor. Divergence is zero. That's the Faraday cage.